# How to add component dynamically through custom directive

Tags: angular

I want to write one custom directive, which will add component dynamically based on some logic inside the div, on which i've used my custom directive.

I tried using componentFactoryResolver and viewContainerRef.createComponent to add component dynamically

```
<div myDirective> 
   <!-- dynamically add component through directive -->
   <span>Hello</span> 
</div>

// my custom directive

myDirective {
    constructor( private element: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer,
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
                    .resolveComponentFactory(myComponent);
        let componentRef = this.viewContainerRef
                    .createComponent(componentFactory, 0);
    }

}
```

Actual result: component is getting created after the div, 
Expected: component should be added inside the div

Answer (score 11):

There [was historical reason](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8529#issuecomment-217718704) to place dynamically created component next to the host element.

But you can change this behavior by just moving your created element inside host element.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);

    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    const host = this.element.nativeElement;
    host.insertBefore(componentRef.location.nativeElement, host.firstChild)
  }
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/xugSUCV2zyQJ9xsHHNuc?open=app%2Fmy.directive.ts)**

Comment: Worth mentioning, the Component Factory Resolver (and Component Factories in general) are deprecated in recent Ng versions 

https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver

Comment: With @jarodsmk's comment in mind, I was able to use this approach while simply omitting the `componentFactory` step. So the call to `createComponent` became `createComponent(DynamicComponent)`

Comment: If anyone is interested in `host` variable type, you can first type `element` in constructor like this: `private element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>` then `const host: HTMLElement = this.element.nativeElement;`

Answer (score 2):

you can use ng-template for this:

```
<div> 
<ng-template myDirective>
   <!-- dynamically add component through directive -->
</ng-template>
   <span>Hello</span> 
</div>
```

check this example I just created on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamicomponents).

Hope this works!

**Note:** If you want to load components both lazily and dynamically check [Manfred Steyer](https://twitter.com/ManfredSteyer) Presentation in [ng-conf](https://youtu.be/E9i3YBFxSSE)

**Update:** I've put some logic inside the directive. Also, I don't understand why you don't want to add ng-template.

Comment: Thanks @mikaovA for the answers, but i don't want to add ng-template everywhere unnecessarily, as I'm going to use this custom directive so many places. Also, directive must have logic to add component dynamically.

Comment: I just updated stackblitz example with some logic inside the directive. I don't know why you avoid using `ng-template`