# angular directive to insert content from the given component view into the host view

Tags: angular

So basically what I need is to create directive that takes the content/html/view of the given component and inserts it into it's host element content/html/view.

Here is what have tried:

host component's template where I apply my directive looks like this:

```
<h3 *myDirective>
    Content of host
</h3>
```

directive's .ts looks like this:

```
import {Directive, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, ComponentFactoryResolver}  from '@angular/core';
import {HoverComponent} from './hover.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    public componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HoverComponent);
    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    const embeddedViewRef = this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

    this.viewContainerRef.insert(embeddedViewRef);
    this.viewContainerRef.insert(componentRef.hostView);
  }
}
```

and the template of the HoverComponent looks just like this:

```
<h1>hover</h1>
```

So what I want is to have at the end in my host's view/html something like this:

```
<h3>
   Content of host
   <h1>hover</h1>
</h3>
```

but instead I get something like this:

```
<h3>
   Content of host   
</h3>
<h1>hover</h1>
```

I have tried also something like:

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HoverComponent);
const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
```

but the result is the same: content of the HoverComponent is added after the host. Of course I can solve this by making changes in DOM directly with something like:

```
this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
```

But making changes directly to the DOM is an anti pattern so I want to avoid that and find a "pure" angular solution for that. So my question is: can I solve my problem with "pure" angular code without doing some anti pattern stuff?

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8817

Comment: hmm, seems to be a known angular issue.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976884/how-to-add-component-dynamically-through-custom-directive